# How to identify WinEdit and WinComboBox objects embedded in a WinListView control in UFT?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I'm automating tests for a desktop application on Windows platform. I'm using HP UFT and VBScript.

In a WinListView control which is used to display a multi-valued list(Each row in the list has four columns in it). After hovering on each row to select it, when mouse click operation is performed on any of the four cells the respective control in that cell shows up(an editbox or a dropdown list)

It seems that the developers have embedded temporary WinEdit and WinComboBox controls in the cells of each row which makes it difficult to use Object spy on them. I succeeded in getting object spy to work on those by holding control key, but the properties of those objects are not unique, for instance ComboBox in the third cell in different rows has the same properties.Posting ObjectSpy results here.

> ```
> **ComboBox in Row 1 Cell 3**
> "Class Name:=WinComboBox",
> "abs_x:=1041",
> "abs_y:=551",
> "all items:=Hours\nMinutes",
> "attached text:=",
> "enabled:=True",
> "focused:=True",
> "height:=21",
> "hwnd:=7602202",
> "items count:=2",
> "nativeclass:=ComboBox",
> "object class:=ComboBox",
> "regexpwndclass:=ComboBox",
> "regexpwndtitle:=Minutes",
> "rightaligned:=False",
> "righttoleftlayout:=False",
> "righttoleftreading:=False",
> "selection:=Minutes",
> "text:=Minutes",
> "visible:=True",
> "width:=90",
> "window id:=7988488",
> "windowextendedstyle:=0",
> "windowstyle:=1342177987",
> "x:=354",
> "y:=257"
> ```

```
**ComboBox in Row 5 cell 3**
"Class Name:=WinComboBox",
"abs_x:=1041",
"abs_y:=619",
"all items:=Hours\nMinutes",
"attached text:=",
"enabled:=True",
"focused:=True",
"height:=21",
"hwnd:=11601852",
"items count:=2",
"nativeclass:=ComboBox",
"object class:=ComboBox",
"regexpwndclass:=ComboBox",
"regexpwndtitle:=Minutes",
"rightaligned:=False",
"righttoleftlayout:=False",
"righttoleftreading:=False",
"selection:=Minutes",
"text:=Minutes",
"visible:=True",
"width:=90",
"window id:=7988488",
"windowextendedstyle:=0",
"windowstyle:=1342177987",
"x:=354",
"y:=325"
```

I have tried selecting rows using WinListView.GetItem but that gives hold of the first cell only which is an editbox and it works. For the remaining three columns I can't find any workaround.
I have tried performing clicks using **WinListView.GetItem().Select** operation providing offset in pixels to click on each cell but that doesn't activates the embedded controls although I see the mouse moving and performing clicks when the test runs.

Record and play didn't provide much insight either as the play operation doesn't replicate the actions successfully every time and uses same and generic names for actions on cells of different rows.

```
WinListView("WinListView Name").WinEdit("Edit").Set "20"
DialogObject.WinComboBox("ComboBox").Select "Hours"
```

Image 1 [The basic WinListView looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uafRV.jpg)
Image 2 [After selecting a row and clicking on a cell the ComboBox or EditBox appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUIs5.jpg)

Comment: Need a lot more information to be able to suggest a qualified approach (i.e. screen prints, how many combo boxes are there or web edits.. etc). But just to give you a head start, even though these fields are embedded within a WinListView, you can still use descriptive programming to get to them. Get all combo boxes and edit boxes on the page. Then use `.highlight` to identify them. Unfortunately this is where I'll have to stop because I don't know enough about the site

Comment: Further to @Zac comment, I would advise that where objects have the same properties, you can usually identify the individual items using the Index property of the object in the OR manager

Comment: Thanks @Zac I've added some images to the post. And while trying to add the elements to Object Repository a popup came _This object has been reloaded, or is no longer available. Use the pointing hand to select the object again._ and when I did that, another popup came saying _The selected object cannot be found in the application. Check the application is open to the correct page or window._ Dave I could not find any property named index. Did you mean "window id" property?